# MAUI Android application not running on Emulator/Real Device

Tags: android, xamarin, maui, maui-android

I have installed VS 17.6.7 (build 417) and created a new default maui application. I tried to run it on emulator as well as real device (Google Pixel 6A) but it is stuck on the screen saying "**Deploying to device**". If you have any idea, request you to answer.

**My .csproj File**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
        <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>TestDotNet7</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>TestDotNet7</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.companyname.testdotnet7</ApplicationId>
        <ApplicationIdGuid>7c2226cf-4c59-4d41-9706-8de6a0a00248</ApplicationIdGuid>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">13.1</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="7.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Following is the **Deploying to Device logs**.

```
Build started 1/8/2024 10:20:55 AM.
__________________________________________________
Project "/Users/akhilgite/Projects/TestDotNet7/TestDotNet7/TestDotNet7.csproj" (Install target(s)):

Target ProcessFrameworkReferences:
    /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.311/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(135,5): message NETSDK1084: There is no application host available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'android-arm'.
    /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.311/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(135,5): message NETSDK1084: There is no application host available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'android-arm64'.
    /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.311/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(135,5): message NETSDK1084: There is no application host available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'android-x86'.
    /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.311/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(135,5): message NETSDK1084: There is no application host available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'android-x64'.
Target _ResolveAndroidTooling:
    Found Java SDK version 11.0.16.1.
    Found Java SDK version 11.0.16.1.
Build started 1/8/2024 10:20:55 AM.
__________________________________________________
Project "/Users/akhilgite/Projects/TestDotNet7/TestDotNet7/TestDotNet7.csproj" (Install target(s)):

Target ProcessFrameworkReferences:
    /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.311/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(135,5): message NETSDK1084: There is no application host available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'android-arm'.
    /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.311/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(135,5): message NETSDK1084: There is no application host available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'android-arm64'.
    /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.311/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(135,5): message NETSDK1084: There is no application host available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'android-x86'.
    /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.311/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(135,5): message NETSDK1084: There is no application host available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'android-x64'.
Target _ResolveAndroidTooling:
    Found Java SDK version 11.0.16.1.
    Found Java SDK version 11.0.16.1.
Target _CheckInstantRunCondition:
    Dex Fast Deployment Enabled: False
Target _ResolveMonoAndroidSdks:
    MonoAndroid Tools: /usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Darwin/33.0.95/tools/
    Android Platform API level: 33
    TargetFrameworkVersion: v7.0
    Android NDK: 
    Android SDK: /Users/akhilgite/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/
    Android SDK Build Tools: /Users/akhilgite/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/32.0.0/
    Java SDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/microsoft-11.jdk/Contents/Home/
    Application Java class: android.app.Application
Target ProcessMauiSplashScreens:
  Skipping target "ProcessMauiSplashScreens" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target ProcessMauiFonts:
  Skipping target "ProcessMauiFonts" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target ResizetizeImages:
  Skipping target "ResizetizeImages" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _ResolveLibraryProjectImports:
  Skipping target "_ResolveLibraryProjectImports" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _BuildLibraryImportsCache:
  Skipping target "_BuildLibraryImportsCache" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _GenerateLayoutBindings:
  Skipping target "_GenerateLayoutBindings" because it has no outputs.
Target _ConvertResourcesCases:
  Skipping target "_ConvertResourcesCases" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CompileResources:
  Skipping target "_CompileResources" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _PrepareUpdateAndroidResgen:
  Skipping target "_PrepareUpdateAndroidResgen" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _UpdateAndroidResgen:
  Skipping target "_UpdateAndroidResgen" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CheckInstantRunCondition:
    Dex Fast Deployment Enabled: False
Target _ResolveMonoAndroidSdks:
    MonoAndroid Tools: /usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Darwin/33.0.95/tools/
    Android Platform API level: 33
    TargetFrameworkVersion: v7.0
    Android NDK: 
    Android SDK: /Users/akhilgite/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/
    Android SDK Build Tools: /Users/akhilgite/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/32.0.0/
    Java SDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/microsoft-11.jdk/Contents/Home/
    Application Java class: android.app.Application
Target ProcessMauiSplashScreens:
  Skipping target "ProcessMauiSplashScreens" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target ProcessMauiFonts:
  Skipping target "ProcessMauiFonts" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target ResizetizeImages:
  Skipping target "ResizetizeImages" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _ResolveLibraryProjectImports:
  Skipping target "_ResolveLibraryProjectImports" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _BuildLibraryImportsCache:
  Skipping target "_BuildLibraryImportsCache" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _GenerateLayoutBindings:
  Skipping target "_GenerateLayoutBindings" because it has no outputs.
Target _ConvertResourcesCases:
  Skipping target "_ConvertResourcesCases" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CompileResources:
  Skipping target "_CompileResources" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _PrepareUpdateAndroidResgen:
  Skipping target "_PrepareUpdateAndroidResgen" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _UpdateAndroidResgen:
  Skipping target "_UpdateAndroidResgen" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _ResolveAssemblies:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/akhilgite/Projects/TestDotNet7/TestDotNet7/TestDotNet7.csproj" is building "/Users/akhilgite/Projects/TestDotNet7/TestDotNet7/TestDotNet7.csproj" (_ComputeFilesToPublishForRuntimeIdentifiers target(s)):

Target _LinkAssembliesNoShrink:
  Skipping target "_LinkAssembliesNoShrink" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _ResolveAssemblies:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/akhilgite/Projects/TestDotNet7/TestDotNet7/TestDotNet7.csproj" is building "/Users/akhilgite/Projects/TestDotNet7/TestDotNet7/TestDotNet7.csproj" (_ComputeFilesToPublishForRuntimeIdentifiers target(s)):

Target _LinkAssembliesNoShrink:
  Skipping target "_LinkAssembliesNoShrink" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _GenerateJavaStubs:
  Skipping target "_GenerateJavaStubs" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _ManifestMerger:
  Skipping target "_ManifestMerger" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _ConvertCustomView:
  Skipping target "_ConvertCustomView" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _AddStaticResources:
  Skipping target "_AddStaticResources" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _GenerateEmptyAndroidRemapNativeCode:
  Skipping target "_GenerateEmptyAndroidRemapNativeCode" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _GeneratePackageManagerJava:
  Skipping target "_GeneratePackageManagerJava" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _GenerateAndroidAssetsDir:
  Skipping target "_GenerateAndroidAssetsDir" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _PrepareCreateBaseApk:
  Skipping target "_PrepareCreateBaseApk" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CreateBaseApk:
  Skipping target "_CreateBaseApk" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CompileJava:
  Skipping target "_CompileJava" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CompileNativeAssemblySources:
  Skipping target "_CompileNativeAssemblySources" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CreateApplicationSharedLibraries:
  Skipping target "_CreateApplicationSharedLibraries" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CompileToDalvik:
  Skipping target "_CompileToDalvik" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _BuildApkFastDev:
  Skipping target "_BuildApkFastDev" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CopyPackage:
  Skipping target "_CopyPackage" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _ResolveAndroidSigningKey:
    Touching "obj/Debug/net7.0-android/android_debug_keystore.flag".
Target _Sign:
  Skipping target "_Sign" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _GenerateJavaStubs:
  Skipping target "_GenerateJavaStubs" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _ManifestMerger:
  Skipping target "_ManifestMerger" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _ConvertCustomView:
  Skipping target "_ConvertCustomView" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _AddStaticResources:
  Skipping target "_AddStaticResources" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _GenerateEmptyAndroidRemapNativeCode:
  Skipping target "_GenerateEmptyAndroidRemapNativeCode" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _GeneratePackageManagerJava:
  Skipping target "_GeneratePackageManagerJava" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _GenerateAndroidAssetsDir:
  Skipping target "_GenerateAndroidAssetsDir" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _PrepareCreateBaseApk:
  Skipping target "_PrepareCreateBaseApk" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CreateBaseApk:
  Skipping target "_CreateBaseApk" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CompileJava:
  Skipping target "_CompileJava" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CompileNativeAssemblySources:
  Skipping target "_CompileNativeAssemblySources" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CreateApplicationSharedLibraries:
  Skipping target "_CreateApplicationSharedLibraries" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CompileToDalvik:
  Skipping target "_CompileToDalvik" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _BuildApkFastDev:
  Skipping target "_BuildApkFastDev" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CopyPackage:
  Skipping target "_CopyPackage" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _ResolveAndroidSigningKey:
    Touching "obj/Debug/net7.0-android/android_debug_keystore.flag".
Target _Sign:
  Skipping target "_Sign" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _Upload:
    Using cached value from RegisterTaskObject
    Found device: 28181JEGR04428
Target _Upload:
    Using cached value from RegisterTaskObject
    Found device: 28181JEGR04428
```

Comment: 1 Is there this: `========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 skipped ==========` ?  2 Try to update your VS / Try other emulator or real device.

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT There is no skipped project and I am trying this on latest VS, emulator and real device, its not working.

Comment: Create a .Net 8 project?  Always in the ["Deploying to device"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU4CU.png) state and no other errors are reported?